# Create Form in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i'm working on an ASP.NET web applications and i don't know how to get the value from my form and how to launch a method on my controller from a view.

This is my View :

```
`<h1 style="text-align:center">Authentification</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            <div class="form-horizontal" style="text-align:right">
                <h4>Veuillez saisir vos identifiants</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Saisir ici votre login" size="40" runat="server" ID="UserName" name="login" CssClass="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Saisir ici votre mot de passe" size="40" runat="server" ID="Password" name="mdp" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="TestConnexion" class="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

`

This is the controller containing the method i would like to use from my Form situated in my view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PhoneTeleX.Controllers
{
public class ConnexionController : Controller
{
    String login;
    String mdp;

 public ConnexionController()
    {

    }

    public ConnexionController(String login, String mdp)
    {
        this.login = login;
        this.mdp = mdp;
        this.TestInfoConnexion(login, mdp);
    }

private void TestInfoConnexion(String login, String mdp)
    {
        DAOConnexionController monDAOConnexion = new DAOConnexionController(login, mdp);
        if (monDAOConnexion.testInfoConnexion(login, mdp))
        {
           // FrmChoix frm = new FrmChoix();
            //frm.Show();
            //frm.getNomLogin(login);
            //GSBFormConnexion.ActiveForm.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connexion impossible, veuillez vérifier votre login et/ou votre mot de passe");
        }

    }
}
}
```

For the moment i can't launch any action from my input button and i dont kkow why.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You forgot the `<form>` element.  A submit button submits a form, but you don't have a form.  You also don't have any action method in your controller to submit the form *to*.  So it's really not clear what you're expecting to happen here or why.

Comment: @David  thx for you fast reply, im gonna try it

Comment: Side note, there is no such word as "Authentification". It's "Authentication" :-). Anyway if you're stuck on the basics such as your stated question, you should probably take the MVC tutorial provided by Microsoft before going any further, it covers all the basics such as creating forms, submitting them, defining your models etc. Then hopefully it'll be a lot clearer to you what you need to do here, and why.

Comment: @ADyson im sorry but the word "Authentification" exist in French and im French ^^

Comment: @WelGalaxy my apologies. Since SO is an English-language site primarily I had assumed it was intended to be English. But now I look closer as your HTML I can see there is other French text there. I have seen this usage before in software which was otherwise written in English. So please forgive my mistaken assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Open the form by rendering the View (Index.cshtml file in the example below).

Action to display form in ConnexionController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() {

    var viewModel = new MyIndexViewModel();

    // do database access, put retrieved data into ViewModel ...

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

The `<form>` tag is rendered by the "Index.cshtml" view and will be submitted to the specified action after the "Submit" button is clicked.

Index.cshtml:

```
@model MyIndexViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Connexion", FormMethod.Post)) {

    @* Show validation errors, if any *@
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @* Use MVC EditorFor to render the inputs *@
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Login)   
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button> @* This will submit the form *@
}
```

After the form was submitted, you will hit the POST Index action in ConnexionController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyIndexViewModel postdata) {
    // validate submitted data
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        // show form again with validation errors
         return View("Index", postdata);
    }

    // process the submitted data ...
    var submittedLogin = postData.Login;

    // on success
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int) HttpStatusCode.OK); // HTTP 200
}
```

Note that web applications do not work in the same way as Windows Forms applications because the different steps run on different computers (server/client). You will benefit from working through the tutorial: [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started).

Comment: Actually my model is not build with Entity Framework, im just using DAO pattern , so i build my sql query in DAOConnexion and i send them through a DB_Factory class

Comment: How you fill the ViewModel is entirely up to you. The important bit is that you have to use a GET - render & serve page - POST pattern.